# Celery status isn't updating (stuck on PENDING)

Tags: python, docker, flask, celery

I'm fairly new to celery, but I was able to implement a distributed work on another container using celery.
When trying to check the celery work status, I'm getting completed even after the task indicated that the work was done.
[image]

[image]
This is the code portion of celery: https://github.com/Formartha/ai1899/blob/main/ai1899/tasks.py

I would be more than happy if someone can aid here and explain what was done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should also provide the Celery up, so in [your server](https://github.com/Formartha/ai1899/blob/main/ai1899/api_routes.py#L171), it should be changed from:

```
result = uc.AsyncResult(task_id)
```

to

```
from tasks import celery as celery_app

result = uc.AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)
```

Alternatively, you can be more generic and not specify the specific task (for a future status of other tasks as well):

```
from tasks import celery as celery_app

result = celery_app.AsyncResult(task_id)
```

Comment: Thanks!
probably something got stuck in the machine, once booted up again everything worked without changes.

May I ask why should I chose to make it more generic?

Comment: Because if you add more tasks in the future, you can use the same server API call to get those other tasks status